# Should my redis-server be a ECR on its own?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-ecr

I'm building a deployment pipeline on AWS for my NodeJs app and I use Redis for caching and creating job queues.
Since AWS ECR can only contain a single container, do I have to create another ECR for my redis instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AWS provides caching out-of-the-box with Amazon ElastiCache:

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/setting-up-a-redis-cluster-with-amazon-elasticache/

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon ECR setup would be targeted towards a single application, for example your website, an API or a microservice. Each ECR repository can support tags so that you can iterate on a new version of the application but you **would not** share a repository with multiple applications.

If you're using Redis there is a [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) that you could use rather than you own so you could also take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some confusion over terms.

ECR stands for [Elastic Container Registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/what-is-ecr.html). A registry can hold multiple *repositories*,
and a repository holds multiple versions of an *image*.

So if you wanted to push a customized Redis image (versus using a standard image or the AWS Elasticache service), you would create a new repository to hold it, within your existing registry.

Note that ECR *registries* are per-region. However, since the repository URL contains the region, you don't need to duplicate your repositories across regions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm totally new to AWS so I'm taking babysteps here :D
I successfully created a nice pipeline for my front-end app but I guess it was easy (well as easy as AWS can be aha) as it was held in a single container but here, it's a bit tricky. Ideally I'd like to keep redis as it's allowing me to leverage job workers and caching.
While developing it's pretty straightforward, I just have 1 container for my NodeJs app and 1 for my redis-server. I launch them both using docker-comspose and that's it.
It looks like it's not going to be as easy as that in production.

Comment: The Redis Cluster AWS has seems ideal. The thing is I don't quite know how to have a smooth transition between my dev environment (with my 2 containers happy to work together) and my prod environement.
I thought about just assigning REDIS_URL in my `.env`with my cluster endpoint but I'm not sure that will work.

Comment: I don't know if my approach is the best one.

Comment: @ThomasFaller - I don't believe that you can access an Elasticache cluster from the Internet -- I believe that it's launched with a private IP address only. There's some more information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/VPCs.html).